# How to dynamic year change using specific day and month using php

Tags: php, date

I have many time try but not solve it.

```
$startyear  = date('Y');
$endyear    = $startyear + 1;

echo $start_date = "$startyear-11-01";
echo "<br>";
echo $end_date = "$endyear-03-31";
```

Output:

```
2017-11-01
2018-03-31
```

In above example work but year change after not work because output generate different

like this

```
2018-11-01
2019-03-31
```

I need this type solution like this:

```
  2018-03-31
```

In above date end after work: 
like this:

```
  2018-11-01
  2019-03-31
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

Comment: @HARDIK your question is vague. Is  `2018-11-01`,`2019-03-31` what you want or  `2018-11-01`,`2018-03-31`  or this.

Comment: Sir i need to specific day and month wise auto year change  like 2017-11-01 to end this date after start date 2018-11-02 this type

Comment: So you declare the `$start_year`, add 1 and declare that value as `$end_year`, then expected the two variables to be the same?  Okay, my solution is: "Unclear What You Are Asking"

Comment: ok sir how to change specific date wise year like current date is 12-16-2017 but i need this date end like 12-17-2018 need to dynamic year change

Comment: @HARDIK you can change year by just adding as year.

Comment: i known please read above question sir perfect after you can understand sir

Answer (score 0):

I think the output you need is :

```
2017-11-01
2018-03-31
```

The code you gave above works fine. That is, it obtains the result as you mentioned.

code :

```
$startyear  = date('Y');
$endyear    = $startyear + 1;

echo $start_date = "$startyear-11-01";
echo "<br>";
echo $end_date = "$endyear-03-31";
```

screenshot :

[image]

Comment: 2017-11-01
2018-03-31 that is fine but this year change 2018 after output is 2018-11-01
2019-03-31  but not a end date 2018-03-31 why change year this reason

Comment: @HARDIK Icouldn't understand what you are talking. Please put punctuations where ever necessary.

Comment: please give me your skype so you can understand perfect sir

Comment: mail me masp203@gmail.com